# Is there any efficient way to do "shuffling" of vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have a large size unsorted array, each element contains a unique integer number,

```
std::vector<size_t> Vec= {1, 5, 3, 7, 18...}
```

I need to shuffle the vector **in such a way**, given a specific number, look for it and then swap it with the number in a new desired position. This swapping needs to be done many times.

Currently I use anther vector **PositionLookup** to remember&update the positions after every swapping. And I'm wondering is there any more efficient way/data structure that can help do this?

Current solution,

```
//look for a specific number "key" and swap it with the number in desired position "position_new" 
void shuffle(key, position_new) 
{
  size_t temp = Vec[position_new];           // main vector     
  size_t position_old = PositionLookup[key]; // auxiliary vector 

  Vec[position_old] = temp;
  PositionLookup[temp] = position_old;

  Vec[position_new] = key;
  PositionLookup[key] = position_new;

}
```

Comment: How "random" do you need it? What sort of efficiency do you need? CPU or memory or code-size or what?

Comment: *I use anther vector to update the positions after every swapping.* A `map` might serve that purpose better.

Comment: I think what you have currently (if I understand right) is already the most efficient solution.

Comment: Efficiency for various solutions greatly depend on usage pattern, so without specifying it such question is meaningless

Comment: @Slava Efficiency means "more efficient than current solution"

Comment: @lorniper do you know that bubble sort is more efficient than std::sort on some data? How efficient is current solution?

Comment: So you have one array of data and one array of indexes.  
You shuffle the data (and do the same operation on the indexes). Then when you want to look up where the data came from you look up its original index? Can you show the code please.

Comment: @LokiAstari, Exactly, the code is implemented as you said by using two std::vector<int> apart from some domain-specifc "position chosen" routine, do you have some suggestion/hint? Later I can try to post the minimum code, but I think without using some "fancy" stuff, the performance of using two vectors can hardly be implementation dependent

Comment: @lorniper: The answer will depend on how you are using the data (ie hwo you are looking up the value). Thus it is really **really** important to show the code. Basically it becomes impossible to answer without the code because English is so in-precise and can have different meanings with context. Show the code and you will get an answer without it the question is really meaningless.

Comment: Is there any range for the integers in the vector?

Comment: @LokiAstari Did you mean something like iter_swap could help?

Answer (score 1):

A couple microoptimizations to start with: If the vector has a fixed size, you could use a [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or a plain C array instead of a `std::vector`. You can also use the most compact integer type that can hold all the values in the vector (e.g. `std::int8_t`/`signed char` for values in the interval [-128,127], `std::uint16_t`/`unsigned short` for values in the interval [0,65535], etc.)

The bigger optimization opportunity: Since the values themselves never change, only their indexes, *you only need to keep track of the indexes.*

Suppose for simplicity's sake the values are 0 through 4. In that case we can have an array

```
std::array<std::int8_t, 5> indices{{2, 3, 1, 4, 0}};
```

Which represents the index of *its* indices in an imaginary array, here `4, 2, 0, 1, 3`. Or in other words `indices[0]` is `2`, which is the index of `0` in the imaginary array.

Then to swap the positions of 0 and 1 you only need to do

```
std::swap(indices[0], indices[1]);
```

Which makes the `indices` array `3, 2, 1, 4, 0` and the imaginary array `4, 2, 1, 0, 3`.

Of course the imaginary array's values might not be the same as its indices.

If the (sorted) values are something like `-2, -1, 0, 1, 2` you could obtain the value from the index by adding 2, or if they're `0, 3, 6, 9, 12` you could divide by 3, or if they're `-5, -3, -1, 1, 3` you could add 5 then divide by 2, etc.

If the values *don't* follow a defined pattern, you can create a second array to look up the value that goes with an index.

```
std::array<std::int8_t, 5> indices{{2, 3, 1, 4, 0}};
constexpr std::array<std::int8_t, 5> Values{{1, 3, 5, 7, 18}};

// Imaginary array before: 18, 5, 1, 3, 7
std::swap(indices[0], indices[1]);
// Imaginary array after:  18, 5, 3, 1, 7

const auto index_to_value = [&](decltype(indices)::value_type idx) noexcept {
    return Values[idx];
};

const auto value_to_index = [&](decltype(Values)::value_type val) noexcept {
    return std::lower_bound(Values.begin(), Values.end(), val)
        - Values.begin();
};
```

It's the same thing if the values aren't known until runtime, just obviously the `values` lookup table can't be `const` or `constexpr`.

```
std::array<std::int8_t, 5> indices{{2, 3, 1, 4, 0}};
std::array<std::int8_t, 5> values; // Not known yet at compile-time

// ... set `values` at runtime to e.g. -93, -77, -64, 8, 56

// Imaginary array before: 56, -64, -93, -77, 8
std::swap(indices[0], indices[1]);
// Imaginary array after:  56, -64, -77, -93, 8

const auto index_to_value = [&](decltype(indices)::value_type idx) noexcept {
    return values[idx];
};

const auto value_to_index = [&](decltype(values)::value_type val) noexcept {
    return std::lower_bound(values.cbegin(), values.cend(), val)
        - values.cbegin();
};
```